# Iterating over multiple lists simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I'd like to iterate over two lists simultaneously.

The first list is just a regular list of elements.

The second list is a list containing multiple lists, each containing elements which are in fact 3-tuples.

I want to perform some function on every element of every 3-tuple in every list inside the second list (if that's understandable). This function will be dependant on an element in the first list, and I'd like it all to run in order.

ie: If I have some list such as `[0,1,2,3,1,5,6,7,1,2,3,5,1,1,2,3,5,6]` as my first list, and `[[(13,12,32),(11,444,25)],[(312,443,12),(123,4,123)],[(545,541,1),(561,112,560)]]` as my second list, I'd like to perform such an operation such that it involves the first element of the first list and the first element of the first tuple of the first list of the second list. I'd like this operation to be iterated using the nth element of the first list, and the nth element of the the tuple bla bla

So if we're looking at what elements will be used together for the operation:

- 0 goes with 13
- 1 goes with 12
- 2 goes with 32
- 3 goes with 11
- 1 goes with 444
- 5 goes with 25
- 6 goes with 312

and so on.

What's happening is that my function will take the element from the second list, its paired element from list 1, use these bits somehow, and output a new value to replace its original second list counterpart. I then want to a construct a replacement/new 'second list' which is the second list after running this function (which uses the information as described above)

Hope this was semi-cohesive, I tried to be as informative as possible. Please inquire if anything is unclear.

Cheers, and thank you for any help you can provide!

**Edit:**

I want to take list 1 and list 2, then flatten list 2.
I then want to iterate over both lists, using some function.
I then want to construct a new list, which uses the outputs from my function, which will just be some 'adjusted' values for my flattened second list, but in the format of how it was originally, tuples in a list of list.

ie: my output could be something like:

```
[[(13,13,32),(11,444,24)],[(313,443,12),(123,4,123)],[(546,542,1),(561,112,561)]]
```

with some of the values either changing a little bit or remaining the same, as a result of being 'passed through' my function.

**Edit#2:**

The ticked solution shows exactly what was needed for this problem!

**Edit#3:**

A few fixes that are needed to the top solution:
How would I fix the code such that if the first list is empty, the output will just be the original second list?
And if the second list is empty, the output should just be an empty list. 
Also if len(list 1) > len(list 2), it will just iterate until the end of list 2, then ignore the excess in list 1, outputting a new list of same format as the original list 2.
And if len(list 2) > len (list 1), it will just iterate for where list 1 can be matched up, but leave the remainder of list 2 intact, rather than chopping it off.

Can I perform all these fixes with some if/elseif/else loops?

**EDIT: I'm still looking to fix these issues, which could be separated/postulated to be a separate query. I've posed a new question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118641/making-a-function-only-run-for-certain-conditions-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118641/making-a-function-only-run-for-certain-conditions-in-python/) if anyone is interested in helping out.**

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is *flatten* the second list, and then you can just e.g. `zip` together with the first.

Comment: So once I've flattened the second list using one of the methods suggested below, performed my operation using an element from each list, how would I create an unflattened replacement/new version of my second list from my outputted data?

Comment: It would help to, for your given example, do the work yourself and show us *exactly* what you want to end up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `itertools.chain` like this:

```
from itertools import chain

first = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
second = [
    [(13, 12, 32), (11, 444, 25)],
    [(312, 443, 12), (123, 4, 123)],
    [(545, 541, 1), (561, 112, 560)]
]    
zip(first, chain(*(chain(*second))))
```

**UPDATE**

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# Flatten the second list
second_flattened = list(chain(*(chain(*second))))

# There is probably a better way to achieve this
foo = [add(x, y) for x, y in zip(first, second_flattened)]

# If second is longer we should append unprocessed values
if len(second_flattened) > len(first):
    foo += second_flattened[len(foo): ]

bar = [foo[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(foo), 3)]
second = [bar[i:i+2]  for i in range(0, len(foo) / 3, 2)]
```

Comment: Okay, so if I wanted to say, take the elements out of each list, pair them together, use them in some function which will give an element to use for my new version of list no.2, then put those outputs into a new version of list no.2, how could I go about such a task?

Comment: Did you actually try out the code? Hint: the `zip` result is iterable; try iterating over it and see what you get. I don't understand what you mean by "put into a new version of list no. 2".

Comment: I did, and I'm fine with iterating over the zip function (might have to double check the syntax). I want to use the output of my function (which uses the data from list 1 and the flattened version of list 2) and construct a new list in the same format as list 2, but the values are the outputs of my function.

Comment: Success! Your edit was absolutely perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: A few bonus queries: How would I fix the code such that if the first list is empty, the output will just be the original second list. And if the second list is empty, the output will just be an empty list. Also if len(list 1) > len(list 2), it will just iterate until the end of list 2, then ignore the excess in list 1. And if len(list 2) > len (list 1), it will just iterate for where list 1 can be matched up, but leave the remainder of list 2 intact, rather than chopping it off.

Comment: Have you checked how `zip` function works? Try this: `zip(range(20, 30), range(4))` and this `zip(range(4), range(20, 30))` and you'll what I mean. And about replacing part of the list it should explain the rest: `foo = [1 for x in range(10)]`, `bar = [2 for x in range(3)]`, `foo[:len(bar)] = bar`

Comment: I had a play around with the zip function, so that makes a bit more sense now. I'm still having a bit of trouble understanding what those last 3 things in your comment represented. Is there an easy way to achieve what I'm looking for using an if/elseif/else loop dependant on the relative lengths of my two lists? I'm kind of in a rush to get this implemented, so I would very much appreciate any help for the time being. I will definitely be coming back to this topic to go through it a bit more thoroughly when I get the opportunity.

Comment: Could I use your second batch of code, and only have it run for where both list 1 and list 2 exist (i.e until the list which has less elements runs out of elements), and then keep the rest of list 2 unchanged/not use the excess if list 1 is the longer one? Then I just have to worry about either or both lists being empty...

Comment: if len(second) is less than or equal to len(first), the function should run for all of the elements in second, and then just ignore the rest of first. if len (first) is less than len(second), i want the function to iterate over where there is elements for both, then keep the excess of second the same as how it was originally...

Answer (score 1):

Your second list needs to be flattened by two levels:

```
import itertools
flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable
for i, j in zip(list1, flatten(flatten(list2))):
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this to get each element from second list :

```
from itertools import chain
l=list(chain.from_iterable(list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

python's `itertools` contains `izip` which allows you to zip an arbitrary number of lists using the same syntax as zip. i.e. `izip(l1, l2, l3)`

Comment: In Python 3  `zip_longest()`

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
dict(zip(ListA, eval('[' + repr(ListB).replace('(', '').replace(')', \
'').replace('[', '').replace('[', '') + ']'))
```

I know it's pretty long, but it will return a dictionary containing the output you need.